# VS code load all solution projects in explorer

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I created a solution on (vs code - .net core 3 - ubuntu ) using the following command

```
dotnet new solution
```

then i add 4 projects to the solution

```
dotnet new webapi -o MyMusic.Api
dotnet new classlib -o MyMusic.Core
dotnet new classlib -o MyMusic.Services
dotnet new classlib -o MyMusic.Data
```

now i want to load all the solution items in the explorer of vs code

i can load any project by the following command

```
code -r MyMusic.Api
```

but i want all projects like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI9i0.png)

Answer (score 1):

i fix it by open a new vs code instance by command

```
code
```

after opened a new vs code i opened the solution folder from explorer (ctrl + shift + E) then open folder and choose the solution folder